# Obtener texto (String) de un RadioButton dentro de un RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-asynctask, radiobutton, radiogroup

Quiero obtener el texto del `rabiobutton` seleccionado por el usuario. Tengo 5 `radiobutton` dentro de un `radiogroup` para luego utilizar este campo en un Asynctask e insertar en una BD. el caso es que no puedo obtener el texto.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente

```
        radioGroup=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiog1);
        rbmuybueno=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbmuybien);
        rbbueno=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbbueno);
        rbregular=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbregular);
        rbmalo=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbmala);
        rbmuymalo=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbmuymala);
public void  validarradiobutton(){
    if (rbmuybueno.isChecked() || rbbueno.isChecked() || rbmalo.isChecked() || rbregular.isChecked()  || rbmuymalo.isChecked())
    {

            final String pregunta=preguntaa.getText().toString();


    }
    else
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalificarEvento.this);
        alertaDeError2.setTitle("Advertencia");
        alertaDeError2.setMessage("Selecione una alternativa para continuar.");
        alertaDeError2.setPositiveButton("Entendido", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertaDeError2.create();
        alertaDeError2.show();

    }
```

necesito obtener el texto dentro del **IF** para luego pasarle los parámetros al Asynctask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440259/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-a-radiogroup-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tienes un `RadioButton` para obtener el texto sería:

```
 rbmuybueno=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbmuybien);
 String texto = rbmuybueno.getText().toString();
```

---

Si tienes un `RadioGroup` que contiene `RadioButtons`, primeramente obtendrías el id del `RadioGroup`:

```
int radioButtonId = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

obtendrías una referencia del elemento por medio del id:

```
View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonId);
```

y obtendrías el indice del `RadioButton` dentro del `RadioGroup`:

```
int indice = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

**Para obtener el texto del RadioButton:**

```
 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)  radioButton.getChildAt(indice);
 String texto = rb.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Gracias y disculpa por no responder antes, ya he votado la respuesta ...